# Searching for document using contents of array not working in Cosmos

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have the structure below

I am trying to find an item using ARRAY_CONTAINS

I want to find the items by passing in a Guid and looking for it in the companies array - looking at the companyId property of the object in the array

I then need to return itemName

```
{
    "itemName": "An Item",
    "companies": [
        {
            "companyId": "6fdc235e-69b7-42f9-9917-79411754fef0",
            "companyName": "Test"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried the combinations but none work?

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.companies.companyId = '6fdc235e-69b7-42f9-9917-79411754fef0'
SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.companies, '6fdc235e-69b7-42f9-9917-79411754fef0')
SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.companies.companyId, '6fdc235e-69b7-42f9-9917-79411754fef0')
```

I need to use the best efficiency method here as there will be 32000 items to search

The companies list wont be huge, maybe a max of 10 or so

What am I doing wrong?

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing JSON documents in your array, so you'll need to look for the specific property of the objects you're storing. Something like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.companies, {'companyId':'6fdc235e-69b7-42f9-9917-79411754fef0'},true)
```

You mentioned only needing `itemName`, so you can optimize as:

```sql
SELECT c.itemName
FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.companies, {'companyId':'6fdc235e-69b7-42f9-9917-79411754fef0'},true)
```

The 3rd parameter, set to `true`, allows for partial match when searching for objects in arrays.